# Most successful techniques to cope with emotional aversiveness when faced with tasks outside comfort zone?

Tags: emotion, self-control, procrastination

According to state-of-the-art Psychology research, what are the most successful techniques to cope with / overcome the emotional aversiveness experienced when one is faced with tasks outside one's comfort zone?